# Firebase Invites: Message failed to send

Tags: firebase, react-native, sha1, firebase-invites

I am trying to use Firebase Invite with React Native. I have followed instructions from rnfirebase.io and Google documentations. I can get to the part of showing the contact list from where I can choose who to invite. But when I press the arrow to send the invite, it shows me an error message saying "Message failed to send".

I read the related posts and most seem to suggest to check that the SHA1 matches. I have checked this many times. I have added SHA1 and SHA256 from my debug keystore and using the corresponding google-services.json file in my project. Still the issue remains.

There were some posts that claimed that the issue automatically resolves after two days, as a result of some delay on Firebase side. That sounds really weird. But I can confirm that after two days :)

Anyone else facing this?

**UPDATE:**
I was trying on emulator and it still fails there. On device, it seems to work. Would be nice to have it working from emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be current limitation from firebase-invites. This sounds an interesting feature request. You may file a feature request to their support channel. :)