# Firebase Invites: 400 not found

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I am trying to use Firebase Invites from React Native. It generates a link of the form "https://mysite.page.link/i/" in the invitation, but does not redirect to the deep link I set while creating the invitation. It gives me a 400 Not Found error, even though I have whitelisted the URL pattern from Dynamic Links section on Firebase Console. I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1` by the way.

If I create a fixed dynamic link from the console, that one works. I am guessing the Invite links are special Dynamic Links that have some issues, unless I am doing something wrong. I need to create the links on the fly because the deeplinks will contain user-specific information, so I cannot create fixed links from the console. I am thinking of abandoning this approach and create a Dynamic Link programmatically (non-Invite way) and share it via some React Native Share api.

It is the second problem I am facing while using Firebase Invites ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661305/firebase-invites-message-failed-to-send) to the first one). Can anyone help? Bit frustrated to face these issues from a service like Firebase.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using the Dynamic Links API and sharing rather than using Invites for this case - you'll get a lot more flexibility. That said, if you want to debug the invites link, could you share an example of a full Invites link that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Ian, I have already changed the code since and using Dynamic Links now. I tested Invites now from my device and it seems it is working (taking me to play store). Not sure why I was getting 400 previously. Could be a delay/caching issue in some point. Thanks for your offer to help!